# mod_rewrite: argument is visible if URL refers to a folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following RewriteRule in my .htaccess, which is working fine.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, there is one thing that is troubling me:

- I have a subfolder called "folder"
- I request the URL http://www.example.com/folder
- The URL changes to http://www.example.com/folder/?q=folder

Any other URL works as expected, including http:// www.example.com/folder/

It doesn't make a difference as far as the GET variable is concerned, of course.
But it would be nicer if the argument would not become visible in the browser. I tried adding a slash before index.php, but that resulted in an Internal Server Error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So simple, but I couldn't figure it out myself. Btw, I only needed the first line. The second line prevented URLs referring to ordinary files from being rewritten as well.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize you wanted to rewrite the files as well. If a file exists you typically want to let it show on its own, but your case might be different. Glad it helped - I suggest you accept the answer if you found it helpful.